# Play video if no other video playing

Tags: javascript, video

Hi I have a page with multiple small videos which can be played by clicking on the covering image. How can I stop them playing onclick if there is already one playing? My script is as follows

```
function PlayVideo(aid, vid) 
{

    var myVideo = document.getElementsByTagName("video");

    if (myVideo.paused) {


        document.getElementById(vid).style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById(vid).play();
        document.getElementById(aid).style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById(vid).addEventListener('ended', myHandler, false);

        function myHandler(e) {
            if (!e) {
                e = window.event;
            }

            document.getElementById(vid).style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById(vid).load();
            document.getElementById(aid).style.display = "block";
        }
    } else {
        alert("this is an alert");
        return false;
    }

}
```

Works fine without the if/else statement but any click starts the movie and then several movies are playing at once how do I define the parameters so that IF any video is playing then a new one will not start.

Comment: Please post code that is properly indented. Many people will refuse to help because you're not being careful in asking your question.

Comment: I do apologise - I am fairly new at this game

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`myVideo` is a NodeList, you have to check the value of each video.

```
var allVideos = document.getElementsByTagName("video");
var areAllPaused = true;

for(var i=0; i < allVideos.length; i++) {
   if (!allVideos[i].paused) {
      areAllPaused = false;
   }
}
```

Comment: Cannot believe how quickly you get so many super answers. This one works for me ( I am sure the others would too - will try them) Thank you so much

Comment: @GarthRamsay Be sure to mark one of the answers that worked for you as accepted, click the tick mark.

Answer (score 0):

you could just use a flag to check, ie

```
var videoIsPlaying = false;

function playVideo () {

    if(videoIsPlaying){
        //dont play video
    }else{
        //play video and set to true
        videoIsPlaying = true;
    }

}
```

you'd have to set it on pause etc

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementsByTagName()` will return an array with all the video elements in it. To check if any of them is playing you need to loop through the array and check whether any video is playing:

```
var anyPlaying=false;
for(var i=0;i<myVideo.length;i++){
    if(!myVideo[i].paused){
        anyPlaying=true;
    }
}

if(!anyPlaying){
    //...
}else{
    return false;
}
```